Why is the uncertainty of the Gravitational Constant $G$ many orders of magnitude larger than that of other important fundamental constants?
Why is the numerical range of uncertainty of the Gravitational Constant $G$ many orders of magnitude larger than that of other important fundamental constants?
What are the challenges in precise empirical measurement of the Gravitational Constant $G$?

Why is it so difficult to measure the gravitational constant?

In short, because gravity is weakest force in nature, so the requirement to catch-up with uncertainty makes strict boundaries on measurement sensitivity.

Of all the fundamental forces in nature, gravity is by far the weakest, which makes it hard to set up an experiment in the lab where you can accurately measure G (which is a tiny number). Consider that your own weight is the outcome of all the atoms in your body being attracted to all the atoms in the entire earth, which means that the gravitational force between two (let's say) equal masses in the average (small) laboratory is almost vanishingly small. The uncertainties involved in such delicate measurements (and the ease with which some outside influence can mess up the measurement process) limit the accuracy with which the value of G can be determined.
